# Angular: generic table component, looping object values

Tags: angular

I have a generic table component for a software I am developing, I am having an issue with looping the values for a table component when the table is applied.

Here employeeList is a list of data retrieved from the backend, while the data retrieval is successful, I've bumped into an issue where the table only displays the first row of data while there are many more rows to be shown. I'm guessing this is because this.items has only one object within the parathesis but I need to be able to retrieve all the data coming from the backend.

The codes snippet in ts file of a component where generic table is used

```
for (this.list of this.employeeList) {
          this.items = [
            {
              EmpNo: this.list.empNum,
              Icon: this.list.image,
              Name: this.list.name
            }
          ];
        }
```

For reference this is the html code

```
<app-table
  [header]="header"
  [items]="items"
>
</app-table>
```

The table component was created with a pipe class and some basic codes in ts and html

The pipe class:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'TableData'
})

export class TableDataPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(obj: any) {
      const result = [];
      for (const key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          result.push(obj[key]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help regarding this! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code :-

```
for (this.list of this.employeeList) {
          this.items = [
            {
              EmpNo: this.list.empNum,
              Icon: this.list.image,
              Name: this.list.name
            }
          ];
        }
```

to

```
  this.items = [];
for (this.list of this.employeeList) {
              this.items.push(
                {
                  EmpNo: this.list.empNum,
                  Icon: this.list.image,
                  Name: this.list.name
                }
              );
            }
```